# How to dilate binary image from outside-to-inside?

Tags: image-processing

I have a binary image of a line, like this one:

[image]

What I'd like to do is to dilate the line, but only towards the 'inside' of the line. That is, to add white pixels towards the center of the image, using `DiskMatrix[]` or any other kernel of a given radius/size. I've been trying to find ways to do this for a bit but I have no idea where/how to begin.

Thanks!

Comment: `WatershedComponents[img]//Colorize//Binarize`

Comment: @b3m2a1 yeah, this works by filling the entire 'inside'. But what I really want is to control how much does it fill, that's why I mentioned the kernel size. Thanks!

Comment: Ah you can use `Dilation` as usual and use that as a mask to clip off anything _outside_, e.g. `Dilation[woof, 50]*mask` will give you a nice result if `woof` is the OG image and `mask` is what comes out of that

Comment: Hmm. I see. If you add it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the `Manipulate` is fun:

```
woof = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKnlk.png"];
mask = WatershedComponents[woof] // Colorize // Binarize
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[Dilation[Binarize@woof, i]*mask, {i, 1, 100}]
```

[image]